# Replace specific words in python

Tags: python, replace

If I have a string "this is", and I want to replace "is" to "was". When I use `replace ("is", "was")`, I got "thwas was", but what i am expecting is "this was",
is there any solution?

Comment: `str.replace(" is", " was")`

Comment: @MattDMo:  `"this island is".replace(" is", " was")` => `"this wasland was"`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski true. In that case, regex is probably the best bet.

Comment: Use regex with word boundaries(`\b`).

Comment: Does it need to work on arbitrary sentences? Because 90% of replace-based potential answers are going to fail if "is" is capitalized, or comes right before a punctuation mark, or appears right at the beginning or end of a string, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do something more sophisticated than a regular string replace. I'd suggest using Regular Expressions ([the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)), and using the `\b` escape sequence to match *word boundaries*:

```
import re
re.sub(r"\bis\b", "was", "This is the best island!")
```

Result: `'This was the best island!'`

By using the pattern `r"\bis\b"` instead of just `"is"`, you ensure that you only match "is" when it appears as a stand-alone word (i.e. there are no numbers, letters or underscore characters directly adjacent to it in the original string).

Here's some more examples of what matches and what doesn't:

```
re.sub(r"\bis\b", "was", "is? is_number? is, isn't 3is is, ,is, is. hyphen-is. &is")
```

Result: `"was? is_number? was, isn't 3is was, ,was, was. hyphen-was. &was"`

Comment: @BhargavRao - Note how `\b` treats punctuation, plus the start/end of the string. Your answer works in a more specific set of situations. This is a bit more general. It really depends on the OP's desired behavior.

Comment: Well we have to wait for the OP then. :)

Comment: @SihanWang:  You'll still need to handle capitalization: `"Is this the best island?"` won't change `"Is"` to `"Was"`.  Although regex allows flags to handle case, it would probably be clearer to deal with capitalization with a another call `re.sub`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - That's a good point, but I think that's a comment for the _question_, not my answer, right?

Comment: @DaoWen:  It's only relevant if the OP decides to use your answer.  That's why I commented here.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - 1) *"Although regex allows flags to handle case..."* The flags only handle the _pattern_ string—the replacement string would still be in whatever case you provided. I agree doing two separate `sub`s is the easiest solution here. 2) I think pointing out to the OP that the question might not be general enough (not mentioning capitalized words) would make more sense than posting the same comment on every answer. If that's actually important to the OP, then the OP is free to clarify.

Comment: @DaoWen:  Well, you can also provide a replacement function rather than a replacement string, but that gets more complicated.  Regarding the placement of my comment, would it help to know I upvoted your answer?  I get the feeling you perceive my comment to be a knock against your answer.  It is not.  It is an excellent answer that handles way more corner cases than the OP asked about.  I just wished to point out one more corner case that may be relevant *in the context of your excellent answer*.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - I had no idea that you can provide a function as the `repl` argument! (I guess I should have read the documentation more closely.) That's a neat feature! Anyway, no, I didn't take that as a knock against my answer. I just felt it was more of a comment on the scope (or lack thereof) of the OP's question rather than my answer. But that whole discussion is kind of moot now since all the other answers were deleted... Anyway, thanks for your comments! I learned something today. ^_^